# how to free temp memory on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have web server on ec2. I am writing ~200Mb file in /tmp usin fs.writeSync function, after uploading that file to AWS-S3 and removing using fs.unlink() function. This cycle can continue some days.

But after ~15 iterations it throws Error:

```
ENOSPC: no space left on device,
```

write What I am doing wrong, any help/suggestion on the above issue will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `fs.unlink()` call is failing. Check the return value to verify.

`fs.unlink()` could be failing because your other code has failed to close the file.

Note: I recommend that you another small EBS volume to your instance and manage your temporary files on that volume. Your use case can cause disk full conditions on the root volume which can cause the OS or web server to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have found the issue.
[File descriptor should be closed after/before deleting](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=739150) the file.

Comment: `unlink` does what its name implies -- it removes the directory entry.  The filesystem doesn't actually free the space until the last descriptor is closed.